# ubuntu terminal -- how to get back prompt after message that takes away prompt?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal

I'm doing something in terminal on ubuntu.

I have a message like "please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing."

Ok, great. Thanks ubuntu.

But when I press enter, it goes to a new line without any prompt.

How do I get the prompt back?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I got the answer:

Ctrl + C is a the standard *nix way of signaling a process to abort. It's the equivalent of CTRL + ALT + Delete in Windows.

Comment: It's not equivalent to C+A+D.  Ctrl+C is the same thing for Windows, when the process is running within the command-prompt environment.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C - "Control-C as an abort command was popularized by TOPS-20 and TOPS-10 and adopted by other systems including Unix. It was also adopted by Digital Equipment operating systems, from which it was copied to CP/M and thus to MS-DOS and Microsoft Windows."